# Проверка на наличие обновлений в html файле после перезагрузки страницы

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

В общем, задача стоит такая - сделать скрипт, который будет проверять сайт (html файл) на добавления/удаления боков div, а также будет проверять изменения текста в этих блоках. Данный функционал должен работать после перезагрузи страницы.

```
   <div class="body">
  <h1 class="zag">Mutation observer</h1>
  <div class="tab">
     <ul>
        <li>Первый</li>
        <li>Второй</li>
        <li>Третий</li>
        <li>Четвертый</li>
        <li>Пятый</li>
     </ul>
  </div>
```

Выше предоставлен мини пример кода. Скрипт должен проверять табличные элементы при внесении в `<ul>` и `<li>` изменений.
Условно, если я в `<li>Пятый</li>` вместо "Пятый" напишу любой другой текст и обновлю страницу - скрипт сообщит об этих изменениях, что в блоке с классом tab в теге `<li>` был изменен текст на *Любой другой, который был прописан в html*
Пытался реализовать через MutationObserver - но данный скрипт работает только в том случае, если изменения в DOM происходили именно на сайте, а не в файле html. И при внесении изменений в html - скрипт не сообщил об этих изменениях.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как можно реализовать данный функционал на сайте? Чтобы при изменении в блоках элементов или текста и обновлении страницы скрипт сообщал об этом.
Если встанет вопрос, как именно нужно, чтобы скрипт сообщал об изменениях - нужно чтобы изменения скрипт отправлял на почту